# Не удаётся неявно преорбазовать тип данных при парсинге json'а c# newsoft.json

Tags: c#, json

Есть такой JSON:

```
[{
  "quoteText": "You can observe a lot just by watching.",
  "quoteAuthor": "Yogi Berra"
},
{
  "quoteText": "A house divided against itself cannot stand.",
  "quoteAuthor": "Abraham Lincoln"
},
{
  "quoteText": "Difficulties increase the nearer we get to the goal.",
  "quoteAuthor": "Johann Wolfgang von Goethe"
}]
```

Для него созданы 2 класса Rootobject и Class1:

```
 public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string quoteText { get; set; }
    public string quoteAuthor { get; set; }
}
```

Пытаюсь его десериализировать вот так:

```
Quotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(Quotes_data);
```

Но всё равно выдаёт ошибку:

```
Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApp1.Rootobject>" в "ConsoleApp1.Rootobject"
```

Comment: Зачем вам тут `RootObject`? У вас JSON начинается с объекта (`{}`) или массива (`[]`)?  Наверно массива, верно? А в массиве у вас что? Объекты, содержащие свойства. Теперь я думаю понятна структура вашего JSON?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ суть в том, что если просто разбивать файл на массив словарей, то пишет, что невозможно использовать в данном контексте JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>(Quotes_data), решил вставить джсон через классы и пытаться распарсить его как массив класса с 2 строками

Comment: `как массив класса с 2 строками` где это вы увидели у себя? Я лично вижу массив класса, который содержит массив другого класса. Поймите наконец структуру вашего JSON! Замените `List<Rootobject>` на `List<Class1>` и вот тогда у вас будет "массив класса с 2 строками".

Comment: извините, описался. Понятное дело, что каждый элемент массива json, должен расскладываться в ещё 1 массив с 2 строками. Просто я не понимаю саму ошибку

Comment: Вот ваш [JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOunh.png), как видите это простой массив объектов (классов), вы же его пытаетесь засунуть в массив объектов (Root), где каждый еще содержит массив классов. То есть по вашей логике у вас [такой JSON](https://pastebin.com/csgHAeme) ([визуально](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJTun.png)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ всё спасибо, просто пытался подобное решение 30 минут назад, не работало)

Answer (score 0):

Помогло сделать так:

```
static public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Quotes;
Quotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(Quotes_data);
```

Comment: Почему не `Class1`, а `Dictionary<>`?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вам не нужен объект RootObject. У вас в JSON записан массив объектов, а не объект с массивом внутри.

Если попробовать вот так, все получается

```
public class Class1
{
    public string quoteText { get; set; }
    public string quoteAuthor { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonObj = "[{\"quoteText\":\"You can observe a lot just by watching.\",\"quoteAuthor\":\"Yogi Berra\"},{\"quoteText\":\"A house divided against itself cannot stand.\",\"quoteAuthor\":\"Abraham Lincoln\"},{\"quoteText\":\"Difficulties increase the nearer we get to the goal.\",\"quoteAuthor\":\"Johann Wolfgang von Goethe\"}]";
        var deserializedObjec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(jsonObj);

    }

}
```